# Setting up F# in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, f#, functional-programming

Are there any decent tutorials for setting up F# in Visual Studio 2005? Everything I have found points at VS2008.

ie: 'F# projects' under projects, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the CTP release of F# doesn't support VS 2005. Two options:

1. Use 1.9.4.19, the most recent pre-CTP release
2. Download the free [VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=40646580-97FA-4698-B65F-620D4B4B1ED7&displaylang=en) shell and use that instead (I haven't tried it, but apparently it [works](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2007/12/f-in-visual-studio-for-free.html))

Answer (score 2):

[Installing F# Editing for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005](http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/install.aspx)

That page also links to [Don Syme's F# blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/), which has a lot of useful stuff on working with F# in VS, including a demo of [F# intellisense in VS2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2005/01/29/362865.aspx).

Comment: Sorry but that is a dead link.